# terminology emulator lacks generic players in Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: lubuntu, terminology

`terminology` installed (`apt update` + `apt install`), and runs fine in a Lubuntu 16.04 fresh installation.
But when trying to display a picture (or show thumbnail images with `tyls`), it always raises this error:

```
$ tycat titan.png
ERR<1714>:emotion-generic modules/emotion/generic/emotion_generic.c:1838 _players_load() no generic players available



$
```

followed by a blank space which is the size of the picture to show.

Tried to install the `generic players` following these instructions:

```
wget http://download.enlightenment.org/rel/libs/emotion_generic_players/emotion_generic_players-1.17.0.tar.gz
tar -xzf emotion_generic_players-1.17.0.tar.gz
cd emotion_generic_players-1.17.0
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
```

but did not work:

```
checking for EMOTION... no
configure: error: Package requirements (emotion >= 1.17) were not met:

No package 'emotion' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables EMOTION_CFLAGS and EMOTION_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

Also installed `vlc`, just in case it might need it, but nothing changed.

Update: Compilation worked for version 1.8.2 (emotion_generic_players-1.8.2):

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
emotion_generic_players 1.8.2
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration Options Summary:
  Build Profile..........: dev

Players:
  VLC....................: yes

Compilation..............: make (or gmake)
  CPPFLAGS...............: 
  CFLAGS.................: -g -O2
  CXXFLAGS...............: 
  LDFLAGS................: 

Installation.............: make install (as root if needed, with 'su' or 'sudo')
  prefix.................: /usr
  emotion generic players: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/emotion/generic_players/linux-gnu-x86_64-1.8.6
```

but the problem remains after `make` and `make install`: `ERR<4002>:emotion-generic modules/emotion/generic/emotion_generic.c:1838 _players_load() no generic players available`

Comment: Apparently, emotion-generic-players are not present in Debian repositories so you indeed have to compile them by hand. What the error message tells you is that you're lacking the emotion library, which is present in the repositories. Could you install libemotion-dev and retry?

Comment: @lgeorget It's weird, cause the library is already installed: `libemotion-dev is already the newest version (1.8.6-2.5).`, and it keeps reporting an error: `Requested 'emotion >= 1.17' but version of emotion is 1.8.6`.

Comment: Ok so the library available in the repository is too old. Library emotion 1.18 is still experimental (https://packages.debian.org/experimental/libemotion-dev). I think your best option would be to look for an older release of emotion-generic-players, compatible with emotion 1.8 (maybe emotion-generic-players-1.8 if they release their apps along with the library).

Comment: @lgeorget I've tried 1.13, but same result: `configure: error: Package requirements (emotion >= 1.13) were not met: Requested 'emotion >= 1.13' but version of emotion is 1.8.6`.

Comment: Yup, that's the same problem, because 1.13 is also too recent for library 1.8.6. Try release 1.8.

Comment: You may have more luck with this one: https://download.enlightenment.org/rel/libs/emotion_generic_players/emotion_generic_players-1.8.2.tar.gz

Comment: @lgeorget Correct! Now it compiled the generic players libs (see update), but the problem remains (even after removing and installing again `terminology`, and rebooting the system).

Comment: Are you sure you have run `make` and `make install` after `./configure`? The text you posted in your question shows only the output of `./configure`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55966/discussion-between-nightcod3r-and-lgeorget).

Comment: @lgeorget Hi again, may you'd like to comment in this related question, addressing how to display pictures in terminal emulators: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/368859/91304

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Things can get really hard if not installed in the proper way. This is how it worked for me:

Firstly, remove all previous stuff

```
sudo apt-get remove enlightenment terminology
sudo apt autoremove
```

Then, follow these instructions

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:niko2040/e19
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install enlightenment terminology
```

This adds a repository curated by a maintainer involved in Enlightenment and installs packages `enlightenment` and `terminology` from this repository instead of the older (currently) non-working packages available in the official Ubuntu repositories.

Logout and login again, no need to select the Enlightenment desktop environment (as the webpage suggests). Now, thumbnails, pictures and video show up in Terminology.

credits: [webpage](https://www.enlightenment.org/distros/ubuntu-start).

(Thanks to @lgeorget for all his help in getting to the solution.)