# How to display inline images in a terminal that update on scroll with w3mimgdisplay

Tags: terminal, scrolling, w3m

The `w3mimgdisplay` program displays images in buffered terminal emulators. This is how: http://blog.z3bra.org/2014/01/images-in-terminal.html . But it is not very well documented. As pointed out in the post, this [thread](https://www.mail-archive.com/mutt-users@mutt.org/msg34447.html) is probably the best you can get.

Now, the problem is that the image does not stays when the terminal scrolls up. This [post](https://www.mail-archive.com/mutt-users@mutt.org/msg34445.html) argues that "`w3m` uses it as a persistent process to handle scrolling", but prefixing the command in line 7 with `nohup` or subfixing with `&` does not make any change. (And it's hard for me to trace back the use of `w3mimgdisplay` in `w3m`.)

So the question resumes as how to execute this command line as a persistent process:

```
echo -e "2;3;\n0;1;0;100;0;0;0;0;0;0;./image.png\n4;\n3;" | /usr/lib/w3m/w3mimgdisplay
```

Update:

Tested on `gnome-terminal` on Lubuntu 16.04.

This is the [X-face patch](http://www.df7cb.de/projects/mutt/x-face/patch-1.5.13.tamo.w3mface.2) by Tamo referred in the post above.

Comment: Not sure if this works outside of OSX, but have you looked into `imgcat`?  https://github.com/eddieantonio/imgcat

Comment: @DopeGhoti The resolution it provides is quite low, w3mimgdisplay does a much nicer work. Actually, on OSX you have other solutions that do the job, but won't work for Linux.

Comment: The resolution by default is scaled to fit your terminal to avoid horizontal scrolling.  There are options to override this.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Right. Problem is that if I just keep pressing the intro key, when it is supposed to scroll up (or after changing workspaces), it simply dissapears, the program is not persistent.

Comment: I suppose that unreliable persistence (I cannot replicate the disappearing images you suggest) may be something that one has to endure as a price for hacking image support into a _terminal_ emulator.

Comment: @DopeGhoti You mean that your images do NOT dissapear? Having the prompt is at the very end of the window, you execute the command, the image shows and stays? In my case, with gnome-terminal on Lubuntu 16.04, the images shows and vanishes immediately after the scroll that the prompt forces.

Comment: Confirmed.  if I `imgcat /path/to/swanky.png; ls -1 /`, I can scroll back to and fro over the image with impunity.  The only machine I can test on right now is iTerm2 on a Mac, though.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Agreed. `Terminology` is an emulator that also deals with scrolling, actually w3m implements persistence and wonderfully allows scrolling. The problem here is how to use `w3mimgdisplay` in that way, cause it's supposed to work in non-Mac platforms and with official software only (`Enlightenment`, which includes `Terminology`, is third-party). I've updated the title accordingly.